# ModRewrite rule for only path part of URL

Tags: regex, .htaccess

everyone.
I have rule in my .htaccess :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} goth|emo|piercing|tattoo|tattoo|body%20art [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^$ http://domain.com/?template=goth [R]
```

I need to rewrite this rule so that it would find words goth|emo|piercing|tattoo|tattoo|body%20art only in path part of the referer, without domain name.
I.e.:

```
goth.com/index.php - no redirect
site.com/goth.php - redirect
```

Comment: Why don't you just use `RewriteRule ^/.*?(goth|emo|piercing|tattoo|body%20art|body art).*?$ http://domain.com/?template=$1 [R]`?

Comment: My code is generated by third part script. I'm not good at all with htaccess, so any help is welcome. Will try your solution, tanks!